# how to deal with shared file permissions in standalone spark cluster?

Tags: apache-spark

We are setting up a spark cluster using the standalone deploy method. Master and all workers are looking at a shared (networked) file system. (This is a cluster that is spun up every now and then to do heavy lifting data wrangling, no need for the (beautiful but intense) HDFS).

The services are running as user `spark` with group `spark`. My user is a member of group `spark`. When I start a session, an application gets created on the cluster. That application can read any file on the shared file system that is readable by the group spark.

But when I write a file to it, in this setup (for instance: `orders.write.parquet("file:///srv/spark-data/somefile.parquet")`), the various steps are performed by different users - depending on which service in the application is performing it.

It seems that the directory is created by my user. The the `spark` user writes files to it (in _temporary). And then my user gets to move these temporary files to their final destination.

And this is where it goes wrong. These temporary files only have `read` access for the group `spark`. Therefore my user cannot move them accross to the permanent place.

I have not yet found a solution to either a) have all workers run under my user account or b) have the file permissions on these temporary files as `read + write`.

My current work-around it to create my session as user `spark`. That works fine, of course, but is not ideal for obvious reasons.

Comment: Could you use something like Ceph/Gluster/Minio as a shared filesystem? I don't picture Spark being useful for shared services on a single machine. Especially dealing with the overhead of reading the file entirely before distribution of its possible splits

Comment: Hey cricket -- this is a shared networked file system where we have multiple spark workers (running on their own box) attached to

Comment: My suggestion would be to define a service group, not single accounts. Make these input/output directories RW for the whole group of individual user accounts within it

Comment: Hi cricket -- do you mean something else than the standard user group? As I stated in my question, the temporary files are created by user `spark` but with read-only rights for the group `spark`. My user (who is part of the group `spark`) can therefore not move it